# Usage of budget speaking about time

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage

Can we use budget/budgétiser in colloquial French speaking about time?

> Time budget for Part 1: Approximately 5 minutes
>
> Budget de temps pour la première partie : environ 5 minutes

or

> How to budget your time ?
>
> Comment budgétiser votre temps ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first sentence:

> Time budget for Part 1: Approximately 5 minutes

I would say:

> Temps imparti pour la première partie : environ 5 minutes

and for

> How to budget your time?

I would say:

> Comment planifier votre temps (imparti) ?

ou

> Comment gérer votre temps.

Comment: Merci. Donc en français budget est utilisé seulement pour argent. À propos budgétiser : est-il acceptable (pour argent) ?

Comment: @dimitris: Budget est principalement lié à l'argent mais peut être utilisé dans d'autres domaines , bien que rarement. [Budgétiser/budgéter](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/budgetiser) est tout à fait acceptable.

Comment: On peut utiliser *budgétiser/budget* avec une indication de temps, mais ce sera alors comme métonymie, pour le coût induit par ce temps. Ex: "on va budgétiser 5 jours de consultance" (= on va budgétiser le coût de 5 jours de consultance).